# allure report installed but not findable

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation

Probably this is similar to any other installation issues, but I tried many options and no luck...

I am trying to install Allure Report on Ubuntu 18.04 (Docker image):

```
sudo apt-get install allure
```

I see that application is already instaled:

```
allure is already the newest version (0.5.0.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

However, I cannot run it by typing: allure.
I tried:

```
whereis allure
```

but also - no luck.

Another command which I tried doesn't look really helpful:

```
selenium@ebb17170c6ad:/$ dpkg -L allure
/.
/usr
/usr/games
/usr/games/Allure
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/allure
/usr/share/doc/allure/CREDITS
/usr/share/doc/allure/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/allure/copyright
```

and another one...

```
selenium@ebb17170c6ad:/$ sudo find / -name allure 
find: ‘/proc/1/map_files’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/1482/map_files’: Permission denied
/usr/share/doc/allure
```

Can you please give me a piece of advice on how to manage that?

**SOLUTION 1:**

The workaround is to download the file and install, below is a command for that, however I thought there is an easier way with the help of apt install ;)

```
curl -o allure-2.6.0.tgz -Ls https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.6.0/allure-2.6.0.tgz && tar -zxvf allure-2.6.0.tgz -C /opt/ && ln -s /opt/allure-2.6.0/bin/allure /usr/bin/allure && allure --version
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Because the above link is not working for me now, I downloaded allure from the Maven repository:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/

I needed to do the same as in Solution 1, but rather manually:

1. Download the file
2. Extract it to /opt
3. Create a link with 'ln' command:

   sudo  ln -s /opt/allure-2.16.0/bin/allure /usr/bin/allure && allure --version

Let me know if we have any other options!

Thanks in advance

Comment: @karel yeah, the description looks weird to me as well. I was a little bit confused. I just want to install an Allure Reporter tool. I am using Docker with ubuntu image but the Allure package is a standard one, it shouldn't be related to whether it is a docker or not

Comment: yep, I just did something like that. Even without the 5th step, this is finally working. However, I thought there is an easier way with the help of apt install. I will update the question with this hmmmm workaround ;)

Comment: What exists in debian repository is allure game. 
https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/allure

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the latest Allure version as .tgz archive.

```
curl -o allure-2.6.0.tgz -Ls https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/generic/io/qameta/allure/allure/2.6.0/allure-2.6.0.tgz   
sudo tar -zxvf allure-2.6.0.tgz -C /opt/   
sudo ln -s /opt/allure-2.6.0/bin/allure /usr/bin/allure  
allure --version
```

You mentioned in the question that you are using an Ubuntu 18.04 Docker image, but there is also a dedicated [Allure Docker Service](https://hub.docker.com/r/frankescobar/allure-docker-service) image.

This docker container allows you to see up-to-date reports simply mounting your allure-results directory in the container. Every time new results appear (generated for your tests), Allure Docker Service will detect those changes and it will generate a new report automatically (optional: send results / generate reports through the API), which you will see by refreshing your web browser.

Comment: thanks for all suggestions.
When downloading from maven (allure-commandline-2.12.1.tgz) and after instalation, it says Allure not found again :( 
However, while using  https://dl.bintray.com/qameta, it is fine (this is a workaround mentioned in the post).

Comment: Regarding the Docker Service, I will need to investigate more. Currently, I am modifying the Dockerfile and the Runner created by my company. I am not sure if we can simply change the existing solution into this dedicated Allure service. And I need to check whether it will be beneficial ;)